# Cleaning a string (probably encoded string) in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read some data which is suppose to be tab delimited but I see a lot of #FO# in it?

I was wondering how can i clean that text out?

Sample snippet

```
    title=#F0#Sometimes#F0#the#F0#Grave#F0#Is#F0#a#F0#Fine#F0#and#F0#Public#F0#Place.#F0#|url=http://query.nytimes.com/gst/fullpage.html?
res=940DEFD71230F93BA15750C0A9629C8B63#F0#|quote=New#F0#Jersey#F0#is,#F0#indeed,#F0#a#F0#hom
e#F0#of#F0#poets.#F0#Walt#F0#Whitman's#F0#tomb#F0#is#F0#nestled#F0#in#F0#a#F0#wooded#F0#grov
e#F0#in#F0#the#F0#Harleigh#F0#Cemetery#F0#in#F0#Camden.#F0#Joyce#F0#Kilmer#F0#is#F0#buried#F
0#in#F0#Elmwood#F0#Cemetery#F0#in#F0#New#F0#Brunswick,#F0#not#F0#far#F0#from#F0#the#F0#New#F
0#Jersey#F0#Turnpike#F0#rest#F0#stop#F0#named#F0#in#F0#his#F0#honor.#F0#Allen#F0#Ginsberg#F0
#may#F0#not#F0#yet#F0#have#F0#a#F0#rest#F0#stop,#F0#but#F0#the#F0#Beat#F0#Generation#F0#auth
or#F0#of#F0#"Howl"#F0#is#F0#resting#F0#at#F0#B'Nai#F0#Israel#F0#Cemetery#F0#in#F0#Newark.#F0
#|work=The#F0#New#F0#York#F0#Times#F0#|date=March#F0#28,#F0#2004#F0#|accessdate=August#F0#21
```

Comment: Where did this come from? (It would be easy just to do `s.replace("#F0$)`, I'm just wondering about other encodings in there).

Comment: THis is a xml dataset which was processed using hadoop

Answer (score 0):

Make `title` and `res` strings and then use `[s.replace(old, new)][1]`:

```
title="#F0#Sometimes#F0#the#F0#Grave#F0#Is#F0#a#F0#Fine#F0#and#F0#Public#F0#Place.#F0#|url=http://query.nytimes.com/gst/fullpage.html?"
res="""940DEFD71230F93BA15750C0A9629C8B63#F0#|quote=New#F0#Jersey#F0#is,#F0#indeed,#F0#a#F0#hom
e#F0#of#F0#poets.#F0#Walt#F0#Whitman's#F0#tomb#F0#is#F0#nestled#F0#in#F0#a#F0#wooded#F0#grov
e#F0#in#F0#the#F0#Harleigh#F0#Cemetery#F0#in#F0#Camden.#F0#Joyce#F0#Kilmer#F0#is#F0#buried#F
0#in#F0#Elmwood#F0#Cemetery#F0#in#F0#New#F0#Brunswick,#F0#not#F0#far#F0#from#F0#the#F0#New#F
0#Jersey#F0#Turnpike#F0#rest#F0#stop#F0#named#F0#in#F0#his#F0#honor.#F0#Allen#F0#Ginsberg#F0
#may#F0#not#F0#yet#F0#have#F0#a#F0#rest#F0#stop,#F0#but#F0#the#F0#Beat#F0#Generation#F0#auth
or#F0#of#F0#"Howl"#F0#is#F0#resting#F0#at#F0#B'Nai#F0#Israel#F0#Cemetery#F0#in#F0#Newark.#F0
#|work=The#F0#New#F0#York#F0#Times#F0#|date=March#F0#28,#F0#2004#F0#|accessdate=August#F0#21"""

title = title.replace('#FO#', '')
res = res.replace('#FO#', '')
```